# validate form data and use PHP to generate the form

Tags: javascript, php, html

So i need to convert an HTML survey I have created into a PHP form. Im very lost with this. It needs to test my regular expressions which I do not have but if someone can use the information I have to help me create some that would be great. Im sure all of my labels can have a regular expression but im not sure how to do this exactly. I also need to validate the form as well. Can someone please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>third html page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" />
</head>
<body style="background-color: #7C7D5E">
    <form name="survey" method="post" action="http://webdev.spsu.edu/formtest.php">
        <div style="background-color: #7C7D5E; text-align: center">
            <header>
                <a href="http://www.spsu.edu">
                    <img src="http://www.spsu.edu/_resources/home2012/images/spsulogo.png" alt="SPSU LOGO" style="float: right;" />
                </a><font size="6" color="#7D0541"><strong>CSE Center for Health Information Technology</strong></font>
                <br />
                <font size="1" color="black"> sponsored by <a href="http://cse.spsu.edu" style="text-decoration: none">the CSE Department</a></font>
            </header>
            <br />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function navigate() {
                window.open(document.getElementById("links").value);
            }

            function clickOn(source) {
                alert("You clicked on " + source + " and the id is " + source.id);
            }

        </script>
        <div id="menu" style="background-color: #AFB090; text-align: center">

            <table width="50%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select id="links" onchange="navigate()">
                            <option value="">Quick Links</option>
                            <option value="HOMEPAGE.HTML">HOME</option>
                            <option value="FACULTY.HTML">FACULTY</option>
                            <option value="SURVEY.HTML">SURVEY</option>
                            <option value="summer_job.HTML">INTERNSHIP</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td align="CENTER"><a href="HOMEPAGE.HTML" style="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">HOME</a></td>
                    <td align="CENTER"><a href="FACULTY.HTML" style="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">FACULTY</a></td>
                    <td align="CENTER"><a href="SURVEY.HTML" style="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">SURVEY</a></td>
                    <td align="CENTER"><a href="summer_job.HTML" style="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE">INTERNSHIP</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="emaillnk">
            <h1><a href="survey.html"><font size="6" face="calibri"><strong>Survey</strong></font></a></h1>
        </div>
        <br />
            <label>
                Last Name:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" size="25" />
            <br />
            <label>
                First Name:           
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname"
                id="firstname" size="25" />
            <br />
            <label>
                Address:
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="address" 
            id="address" size="25"/>
            <br />
            <label>
                City:
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="city" 
            id="city" size="25"/>
            <br />
            <label>
                State:
            </label>
                    <select name="state" id="state">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    </select>
            <br />
            <label>
                Zip Code:
            </label>
            <input type="number" name="zip" 
            id="zip" size="7"/>
            <br />
            <label>
                Email:
            </label>
            <input type="email" name="email"
                id="email" size="25" />
            <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Language Spoken: </th>
                    <td>
                        <span>English 
                            <input type="radio" name="pref_lang"
                                id="pref_lang_en" value="en"
                                checked="checked" />
                        </span>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>Fran&ccedil;ais 
                            <input type="radio" name="pref_lang"
                                id="pref lang fr" value="fr" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>Espa&ntilde;ol 
                            <input type="radio" name="pref_lang"
                                id="pref lang es" value="es" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <label>
                Major Selected:
                    <select name="major" id="major">
                        <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
                        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
                        <option value="SWE">Software Engineering</option>
                        <option value="PHY">Physics</option>
                        <option value="BIO">Biology</option>
                    </select>
            </label>
            <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Term(s) Applying For:
                    <br />
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>2013 ONLY
                                <input name="term[]" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="PT1" value="true" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>2013 - 2014
                                <input name="term[]" type="checkbox" name="full semester" id="FT" value="true" /></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>2014 ONLY 
                            <input name="term[]" type="checkbox" name="spring semester" id="PT2" value="true" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Submitsurvey()" />
        </form>
        <table id="suveryResultsTbl" class="hide">
            <tr>
                <td>Your Last Name is:
                </td>
                <td id="LNameRslt"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Your First Name is:
                </td>
                <td id="FNameRslt"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Your Email is:
                </td>
                <td id="EmailRslt"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <script type="text/javascript">


            function Submitsurvey() {

                if (!ValidateForm()) {

                    return false;

                }


                document.getElementById("survey").submit();

            }

            function ValidateForm() {
                if (document.getElementById('lastname').value.length === 0) {

                    alert("Last Name Field is Required");

                    return false;

                }

                document.getElementById('LNameRslt').value = document.getElementById('lastname').value;



                var chkboxesSelected = 0;

                if (document.getElementById("PT1").checked === true) {

                    chkboxesSelected++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("FT").checked === true) {

                    chkboxesSelected++;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("PT2").checked === true) {

                    chkboxesSelected++;
                }


                if (chkboxesSelected === 0) {
                    alert("At least one MUST be checked");
                    return false;
                }

                return true;




            }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an existing form validation library? Instead of reinventing the wheel. There are plenty jquery (and other) form validation plugins available.

Comment: change your survery into a form... wrap the elements in <form> tags, what are you trying to do with the form once it's submitted?

Comment: In PHP you can use libraries: https://github.com/Respect/Validation and https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best PHP form generation & validation Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203092/best-php-form-generation-validation-framework)